# A problem with alignment to the bottom of the page with different font sizes

Tags: vertical-alignment

I want all my pages' bottoms to fall in the exact same place.

Assume also that I want two different font sizes on one page (first a larger one, then a smaller one), so using the `heightrounded` option of geometry is not an option; also, the *size* of the portion in the larger (default) font may be variable, so putting a fixed, precalculated skip won't help, either.

I tried this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{vgrid}% this is just to help visualize the alignment!
\usepackage[height=14\baselineskip,paperheight=20\baselineskip]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\vspace{0pt plus \baselineskip}
%\vfill
{\footnotesize
\lipsum[2-5]
\par}

\end{document}
```

but the `\vspace` didn't seem to change anything.  OTOH, `\vfill` *did* help.

Why didn't my stretchable `\vspace` work?

Comment: Because you're forgetting that `article`, in one side mode, has `\raggedbottom` in effect. Issue `\flushbottom` after `\begin{document}`.

Comment: Wow, am I really *that* stupid???  However, this is only an MWE; after going to a more sophisticated one, things broke again...  I'll post it in a separate question, though.

Comment: And here it is: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/184597/5626 . BTW, egreg, could you turn your comment into an answer, so that I could accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without specifying `twoside`, the `article` class does `\raggedbottom`, so your flexible glue has no effect.

If you declare `\flushbottom`, either before or after `\begin{document}`, the problem will not appear.

However, declaring `height=14\baselineskip` is not correct, unless you also change `\topskip`, which is the distance of the first baseline from the top of the type area: either

```
\setlength{\topskip}{\baselineskip}
```

or

```
height=\dimexpr13\baselineskip+\topskip\relax
```

in the options to `geometry`, which can be abbreviated into `lines=14`.