# A problem with vertical positioning of `multicols`

Tags: vertical-alignment, multicol

In my [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/184564/5626), I asked about a problem with vertical alignment at the bottom of the page; the solution (provided by egreg) was simple and obvious.  However, here is a less-minimal example (i.e., one closer to my real problem), including `multicols` environment.  The problem (again) is that even a *really* infinitely stretchable glue won't help move the two-column text down, so that its bottom is aligned with other pages.  Any hints?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{vgrid}% here only to help visualize the problem
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\multicolsep}{0pt}
\usepackage[height=11\baselineskip,paperheight=20\baselineskip]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\flushbottom
\lipsum[1-2]

\vskip 0pt plus 1filll
{\begin{multicols}{2}\footnotesize
\lipsum[2-3]
\par\end{multicols}}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem has only partially to do with the way `multicols` handles spacing, there are a bunch of issues and unfortunately some that you will get no automatic answer for.

You are asking for `11\baselineskip` of height which gets you 159.5pt. However on a page the first line has a height of `\topskip` which is 12pt (not 14.5pt).

Now as your first page consists of a single paragraph there is nothing in there to stretch, therefore the page comes out short and you get a warning saying:

```
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active [1{...
```

You could see that this pages is coming out short if you actually put in anything that is allowed to stretch, e.g., a second paragraph. To repar that you would need to substract 2.5pt from your calculated `\textheight` (or use the geometry option that does this for you --- I think there is one).

However if you do this nothing will get better on the second page, unfortunately. The reason is the following:

- the `multicols` environment starts somewhere on that page
- the stuff above (including your `\vskip`) is measured and saved away in some box (therefore your `\vskip` is considered to be 0pt and the `1filll` is not going to make a difference whatsoever later on
- from that the remaining space is calculated (you can see this if you use the `balancingshow` option of `multicol`), i.e.,

  Package multicol: Starting environment with 2 columns on input line 25.

  Package multicol: Current page:
  (multicol)        height=157.0pt: used 101.33331pt -> free=55.66669pt
  (multicol)        needed 50.0pt (for \premulticols ) on input line 25.
- So 55.66669pt are remaining on the page and as the environment is not finished when the page gets full all that `multicols` does is to cut of columns from the galley at the height available. Now 4 lines in `\footnotesize` (12pt) comes out at 48pt which is 6.66669pt short of the column height target. and you should see another bunch of underfull boxes. However, with `multicols` doing so much trials the underfull messages are suppressed as most of the trial would give you those. As a result you see no such warning but the fact is that for TeX the column boxes have a nominal height of 55.66669pt at the end of the day even if they are not properly filled. Again to try it out put something like

  xxx\par \lipsum[2-3]

  in there and you will see how the first column changes downwards.
- Also because the column height is "nominally" making up the rest the two blocks when put together again, just fit and thus the `1fill` has nothing to stretch.

So to come out right, you would need to put in the "right" amount of real space, e.g., 6.66669pt (unless I have miscalculated) but that amount differs each time due to the number of lines in a smaller size or due to the depth of the material above.

So basically you are out of luck in that `multicols` isn't being set up to make this scenario work. I'm a bit wondering about whether or not it can be made to work (or even if some of this could called a bug) and I made a note in my huge list of things to look at  "one day". But don't get your hope up --- chances that this gets a fix are slim (especially as any change there will likely have effects on most documents using `multicols` and if so that would rule it out)

Comment: There *is* the option for geometry: `lines=14`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation!  At least I *know* that I'll have to fix this manually (that's what I did anyway).  And I hope that the LaTeX3 output routine will handle such things...;)

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{vgrid}% here only to help visualize the problem
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\multicolsep}{0pt}
\usepackage[height=11\baselineskip,paperheight=20\baselineskip]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\flushbottom
\lipsum[1-2]

\setlength\multicolsep{2\baselineskip minus \baselineskip}
{\begin{multicols}{2}\footnotesize
\lipsum[2-3]
\par\end{multicols}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work here... I changed `[2-3]` to `[2-10]` and the pages are still "ragged".