# Inconsitent footer position with multicols

Tags: positioning, fancyhdr

A footer created with `fancyhdr` in combination with `multicols` is placed at different vertical positions depending on - as far as I have been able to isolate the issue - wether the page is full or not: On full pages the Footer is placed sligtly *higher* then on not completely filled pages.

The problem is not present when multicols isn't used and for some reason shows itself **on my notebook but not on my desktop PC** although both are running identically configured instances of `MiKTeX 2.9`.

Any idea how I could achieve a consistant behaviour of the footer?

[image]

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}       % Two cols
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[top=1.6cm,bottom=2.8cm,left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,foot=2cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}         % Filler text
\usepackage{fancyhdr} %adaptation of the footers

\pagestyle{fancy}

\footskip = 50pt %push the footer down so it fits with a decal from a bg-img
\fancyhfoffset[LE,RO]{30pt} % push the footer left on even pages so it fits the decal
\fancyhfoffset[RO]{30pt} % push the footer right on odd pages so it fits the decal
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt} %no rule for header
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.0pt} %no rule for footer

\fancyhead{} % clear all header fields
\fancyfoot{} % clear all footer fields

\fancyfoot[LE]{
    \thepage
    \hspace*{0.8cm}
    \raisebox{-10pt}{Test}
}

\fancyfoot[RO]{
    \raisebox{-10pt}{Test}
    \hspace*{0.8cm}
    \thepage
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \section{Main Section}
        \subsection{Main subsection}
        \lipsum
        \lipsum
        \lipsum
    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: works fine here, using miktex 2.9 fully updated today

Comment: @Hendrik I just ran all available updates but the issue persists :-(.

Comment: There is a difference between admin and non-admin update, do both just incase

Comment: @Hendrik Done - no updates are available anymore. I also rebooted the Notebook - still no improvement..

Comment: @HenrikBøgelundLavstsen: I can reproduce this issue (TL 2015, daily updated). Have you looked on the last page?

Comment: Ok i could reproduce it myself now, it happens when using multicols if you dont it work fine. The problem is Raisebox, it work if you have a positive value but not negative, i think your problem relates to this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/184684/34173

Comment: Huh so I guess the answer is: Don't use multicols. I wasn't aware that there actually is a twocolumn option for the article documentclass. Using that, the footer sits where it should. Thanks for the help